# pandas - get_dummies multiplied by quantities

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with Stockcode and quantity:

```
>>>df
    StockCode   Quantity
0   85123A      6
1   71053       6
2   84406B      8
3   84029G      6
4   84029E      6
```

I'm looking for a solution to get the `pandas.get_dummies()` multiplied by the quantity.

The output I'm expecting should look like that:

```
>>>pd.get_dummies(df['StockCode']) ... --> * df['Quantity']
    71053   84029E  84029G  84406B  85123A
0   0       0       0       0       6
1   6       0       0       0       0
2   0       0       0       8       0
3   0       0       6       0       0
4   0       6       0       0       0
```

I can do a for loop to multiply all the dummies by the quantity, but I'm hoping a more "pythonic" solution.

Does anyone know if there is better way to get those corrected dummies ?

Thanks

Larry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.reset_index().pivot('index','StockCode','Quantity').fillna(0)
Out[93]: 
StockCode  71053  84029E  84029G  84406B  85123A
index                                           
0            0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     6.0
1            6.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2            0.0     0.0     0.0     8.0     0.0
3            0.0     0.0     6.0     0.0     0.0
4            0.0     6.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

To fix your code

```
pd.get_dummies(df['StockCode']).mul(df.Quantity,0)
Out[97]: 
   71053  84029E  84029G  84406B  85123A
0      0       0       0       0       6
1      6       0       0       0       0
2      0       0       0       8       0
3      0       0       6       0       0
4      0       6       0       0       0
```

Or `pd.get_dummies(df['StockCode']).values*df.Quantity.values[:,None]`

Comment: A mix of both solution works great --> `df.pivot(columns='StockCode', values='Quantity').fillna(0)`

Comment: @LaurentR aha, you got it :-) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
df.StockCode.str.get_dummies().mul(df.Quantity, axis=0)
```

Reference

[How to multiply each row in pandas dataframe by a different value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105864/how-to-multiply-each-row-in-pandas-dataframe-by-a-different-value)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html