# How to multiply dataframe columns with dataframe column in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to multiply hdataframe columns with dataframe column.

I have two dataframews as shown here:

```
A dataframe,  B dataframe
a b c d          e 
3 4 4 4          2
3 3 3 3          3
3 3 3 3          4
```

and I want to make multiplication A and B.

Multiplication result should be like this:

```
a   b  c  d 
6   8  8  8
9   9  9  9
12 12 12 12
```

I tried just * multiplication but got a wrong result.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`B.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) or [`B.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) which will return numpy array and then you can multiply with DataFrame

Ex.:

```py
>>> A
   a  b  c  d
0  3  4  4  4
1  3  3  3  3
2  3  3  3  3
>>> B
   c
0  2
1  3
2  4

>>> A * B.values
    a   b   c   d
0   6   8   8   8
1   9   9   9   9
2  12  12  12  12
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another variation on @Dishin's excellent answer:

U can use pandas [mul](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) method to multiply A by B, by setting B as a series and multiplying on the index:

```
A.mul(B.iloc[:,0],axis='index')

    a   b   c   d
0   6   8   8   8
1   9   9   9   9
2   12  12  12  12
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with `Series` by selecting `e` column:

```
df = A.mul(B['e'], axis=0)
print (df)
    a   b   c   d
0   6   8   8   8
1   9   9   9   9
2  12  12  12  12
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the mul function, as seen on this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105864/how-to-multiply-each-row-in-pandas-dataframe-by-a-different-value), here is the code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 4, 4, 4],[3, 3, 3, 3],[3, 3, 3, 3]])
val = [2,3,4]
df.mul(val, axis = 0)
```

Here are the results:

```
    0   1   2   3
0   6   8   8   8
1   9   9   9   9
2  12  12  12  12
```

Ignore the indices.